# Tube punctured by broken tire carcass fibre?

Tags: tire, puncture, gravel

My wife's new bike had a puncture in the 650Bx2.4 "gravel" tire shortly after riding on a section of trail where fresh gravel had been spread.  The gravel is crushed granite and quite coarse with many relatively sharp corners.

There was a small spot on the tube where air was escaping.  I found a corresponding spot in the inside of the tube. There was no sign of damage on the outside of the tire, so I assumed a bit of debris had been trapped between tire and tube.  I carefully checked the inside of the tire and couldn't find anything, so assumed the debris had fallen out when I removed the tube.  After patching the tube and putting everything back I wasn't able to inflate the tire.  On inspection, there was a new hole next to the original hole. Feeling the abraded spot on the inside of the tire, it seemed a bit prickly, so I put a patch over the spot on the inside of the tire, patched the tube, and the tire has been holding air for several days and a few rides.

My guess is that she hit a pointy bit of gravel that broke a fibre in the tire carcass or
anti-puncture belt without leaving a mark on the outside of the tire, but it is possible there was a defect in the carcass or belt.  Crushed granite gravel is very common here (and is used in my own driveway). I've had a number of pinch flats in 28 and 25 mm tires when crossing areas of fresh gravel or forced by traffic to ride in loose gravel along the edge of a trail, but I'm a bit concerned that the thinner body of wide "gravel" tires may be vulnerable.  I assume tire sealant would prevent flats caused by a broken tread or belt fibre (for pinch flats sealant just creates a mess).

Comment: Can you add the make/model of the tyre in question.  We will be able to give better answers if we are able to look up the construction of the tyre

Comment: If you have the tyre off in the future, try flexing it inside-out at that point.  There may be a fragment of glass, wire, or perhaps stone in there causing the issue.  It doesn't take much